# Access to a class property dependent on asyncronous content

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, reverse-geocoding, ivar

The goal I want to achieve:
I want to display the user address in a view. The view is taken care of by a view controller . This VC is using the GeoAPI to get access to the user location. The GeoAPI is wrapped around the LocationManager-Class which in turn is taking care of all the locationmanager stuff. In this location Manager class I would like to reversegeocode as mentioned above.

The geoAPI has some convenience methods that can be used to get the information I want.

**GeoAPI:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MFGeoAPI : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *userLocationInfoDict;

+ (MFGeoAPI *)sharedInstance;
- (CLLocation *)getCurrentUserLocation;

@end

@interface MFGeoAPI () {
    LocationManager *locationManager;
    MotionManager *motionManager;
}
@end

@implementation MFGeoAPI

+(MFGeoAPI *)sharedInstance {
    static MFGeoAPI *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[MFGeoAPI alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        locationManager = [[LocationManager alloc] initLocationManager];
        motionManager = [[MotionManager alloc] initMotionManager];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getUserLocationInformation:) name:@"UserLocationInfo" object:nil];
    return self;
}

- (CLLocation *)getCurrentUserLocation {
    return [locationManager getCurrentUserLocation];
}

- (void)getUserLocationInformation:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"OK");
    self.userLocationInfoDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:notification.userInfo];
}


@end
```

Now.. due to the fact of the async character of the reverse geocode function I won't be sure when the dictionary with the user address will be available.

The Location Manager class contains the following:

**Location Manager:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *userLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *userLocDict;

- (id)initLocationManager;
- (CLLocation *)getCurrentUserLocation;
@end

#import "LocationManager.h"

@implementation LocationManager
- (id)initLocationManager {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        if (self.locationManager == nil) {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;

            if (![self.locationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
                UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [servicesDisabledAlert show];
            }
        }
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        [self startFetchingCurrentUserLocationInformation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.headingFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.userLocation = self.locationManager.location;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}

- (CLLocation *)getCurrentUserLocation {
    return self.userLocation;
}

- (void)startFetchingCurrentUserLocationInformation {
    [self delayedReverseGeocodeLocation];
}

- (void)delayedReverseGeocodeLocation {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self reverseGeocodeLocation];
}
- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation {

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.userLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [[placemarks firstObject] addressDictionary];
        if (placemarks.count > 0) {
            NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dict forKey:@"transferDict"];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserLocationInfo" object:self userInfo:info];
        }
    }];
}
```

In the view Controller I would like to get access to the userLocation Information Dictionary that I am passing through the API

**View Controller**

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.userLocation = [[MFGeoAPI sharedInstance] getCurrentUserLocation];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[MFGeoAPI sharedInstance].userLocationInfoDict description]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the userlocationInfoDict is empty. I guess this is due to the fact that my function-call "startFetchingCurrentUserLocationInformation" is returning before the async block returns the values I need. Then I thought by taking care of this through NSNotificationCenter I will be informed when the data is available. But now I am stuck:

What do I have to do to get access to the userLocationInformation passed by the GeoAPI to do it in time when the data has arrived?

Any help appreciated!
Thank you 
Sebastian

Comment: Setting an iVar or property is, presumably, not the goal to your program. Are you trying to notify the things that use that iVar that the field has been updated? If you can give me a bit more context, I can offer much more help.

Comment: Hi Neal, I hope my edited post will help you with that: the basic problem is: I want to display the user location stored in the dictionary passed through by the GeoAPI which is stored in a class property. But it seems to me that my access is "too quick" before results get passed. I have already checked that the data is available and thats fine already. But how do I build that kind of "dependency tree" to make sure that this will work? It seems so easy but I don't get it :) Thank you

Comment: After seeing your code, your problem is fairly easy. Rather than just giving you a solution, I'd rather give you a hint and see if you can figure it out. Don't imagine that the reverse Geocoding will take seconds. Imagine that it will take minutes and it can change periodically. As such, your view controller should expect to have no data on -viewDidLoad and it should be *notified* later when it needs to check for a new location and update the view accordingly.

Comment: Hi Neal, wow... it now works like a breeze! Giving a hint rather than the full solution was very helpful! I think thinking the whole thing through with the help of a hint is so much more powerful! I can't believe that I was so close but did not see it! Maybe you could give that hint as an answer to the question so I can "accept" it? Thank you!!

Comment: I'll probably write it out fully when I get time over the next few days. Lots of people have problems with async programming, so a good example will help them.

Comment: that would be great... feels great to learn something new